# Is there a matlab function that converts a rotation matrix to acceleration vector?

Tags: matlab, rotational-matrices

Given some 3 x 3 rotation matrix with some constant acceleration A, I would like to find the component acceleration the three directions, ie, Ax,Ay,Az.

Though it's not difficult to just "reinvent the wheel", I am wondering if there's a Matlab function that does this already, particular in the Aerospace toolbox?

Comment: The acceleration vector as in the centripetal force?

Comment: In my case A is just acceleration due to gravity. So we assume all the force on the object is from gravity, and the force used to actually rotate the object is negligible.

Comment: Basically I imagine some function that converts rotation matrix to a 3 x1 vector of angles w.r.t. global frame, then decompose the acceleration vector (gravity in this case) into ax,ay,and az. Again, in the interest of not reinventing the wheel, I'd like to see a library function that does this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NxN rotation matrix has N (N-1) / 2 embedded angles. The rotation of a unit right-hand-rule coordinate system into the orientation of R requires these many rotations. In your case there are three angles.

No, Matlab does not have such a built in function. I, too, rolled my own. Take care with the arc-tan's you'll need, certainly use the atan(y, x) form so that you don't lose a 180 deg rotation.

Comment: Any chance your version can be found online somewhere? Or a more complete tutorial of what you just said? I had not thought of the 180 degree rotation prior to this.

Comment: I'm afraid it's unpublished. For the 3x3 just find the angle that rotates e1 to [1 0 0], then find the two angles in R2 that rotate to the remaining axes. Since R = Rx Ry Rz = Rz Ry Rx the answer is not unique. A consistent rotation sequence is all you need.

Comment: have I answered your original question?

Comment: Pretty much. Now that I have a 3 x 1 vector of angles, what is the matrix operation to project the acceleration vector onto each component? As oppose to doing Ax = A * sin(ThetaX), etc.

Comment: I don't know if I can help you further b/c we don't know the coord system of your vector A wrt the coord system underlying your original rotation matrix R. Projections are done with projectors, P (P'P)^-1 P', which relies on inner products, the inner product being a fundamental way to compare two vectors. Perhaps you should ask a separate question (just an idea).

Answer (score 1):

A rotation matrix is always a relative information, probably it gives the orientation relative to [1 0 0]. To get the components, you have to multiply:

```
R*[A;0;0]
```

Comment: Actually, relative to eye(N), not [1 0 0].

Comment: `eye(3)` is no rotation, that is obvious, but what is a vector with no rotation? For some reason I don't really understand some libraries assume `[0,1,0]` to be a un-rotated vector.

Comment: I commented on the orientation is relative to eye(N), not one vector in the subspace. A vector exists independent of a coordinate system. Relations between vectors are described via inner and cross products (in R3). A matrix resolves the coordinate system of a vector onto our own basis, we are imposing a basis when we fill in the rotation matrix entries.

Comment: This turns out to be a simpler solution. except in my case the acceleration vector is [0,0,A]'